# Pushing a new view after an item was tapped in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have a simple list populated from json. When tapping one of the items i want a new view to appear. The List is inside an Ext.navigation.View.

**My controller**

```
Ext.define('Trainz.controller.StationListController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    models: [
        'Station'
    ],
    stores: [
        'Stations'
    ],
    views: [
        'Main'
    ],

    control: {
        "list": {
            itemtap: 'onListItemTap'
        }
    }
},

onListItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    console.log(record);
}

});
```

And here is the (now empty) view i want to push

```
Ext.define('Trainz.view.StationDetailView', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',

config: {
}

});
```

Guessing i have to put something in the `onListItemTap` function but for the life of me I cant figure out what. Tried over four different code snippets from Google and just got errors back. Whats the proper way?

I'm using **Sencha Architect** if that makes any difference.

**Here is the complete initial view for reference:**

```
Ext.define('Trainz.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

config: {
    tabBar: {
        docked: 'bottom'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'navigationview',
            title: 'Stations',
            iconCls: 'maps',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'list',
                    title: 'Stations',
                    itemTpl: [
                        '<div>{Namn}</div><div style="float:right; margin-right: 1.5em;"></div>'
                    ],
                    store: 'Stations',
                    grouped: true,
                    indexBar: true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

});
```

Comment: You need need to retrieve your navigationview and then do navigationView.push(yourNewView); http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-method-push

Comment: or dataview.up('navigationview').push(yourNewView)

Comment: @TDeBailleul I just found this in the Using Navigation View tutorial. Post your comment as an answer and ill accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need need to retrieve your navigationview and then do

```
navigationView.push(yourNewView);
```

or

```
dataview.up('navigationview').push(yourNewView)
```

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-method-push

Hope this helps